# How to use numpy linalg solver for multi-dimensional use?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to determine a solution for an overdetermined system, I have code which is running but I think it looks ugly since I have to do so many for-loops when I feel like it should be more simply, part of it is currently looking like:

```
for s in range(4):
    for m in range(p):
        storing_list = []
        for n in range(tree_length):
            mu.append(tree[n][s][m])
        Q, R = np.linalg.qr(storing_list)
        Qb = np.dot(Q.T, mu)
        x_qr = np.linalg.solve(R, Qb)
```

I can't really post all of my code since I'm generating my data from a file. As you can see, I have to get values from the tree, put them into a list, and then use that to solve the system, is there a more clean way to make this computation? Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you provide more details about the system?

Comment: You need to at least tell us the dimensions of the various arrays.  Does this actually run?  `storing_list` is `[]`.  `mu` is a list of unknown content and size.  What's multidimensional about this?  The `linalg` code is written for 2d arrays.